# Best way to package and deploy Python Application

Tags: python, opencv

I am involved in a project where we have developed an application for a Raspberry Pi that among others use a specific version of openCV and librealsense (for the Intel RealSense camera). Until now, whenever we had to install on a new Raspberry Pi we would clone the git repository and build openCV and librealsense from source using CMake. This is a time-consuming process, which we would like to eliminate as we might have to deploy a larger number of Raspberry Pi's in the future.

I have looked into the possibility of generating a .whl for opencv and librealsense to be installed using pip but I must admit that I'm not too experienced in how to do this, when it depends on compiled C-binaries. So my question is two-fold:

How would you choose to speed up such as deployment process?
If .whl generation is the way to go, can anyone help me getting started with for example generating a .whl for openCV?

Hope all this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Is building from source always necessary? Can't you just build once and distribute binaries?

Comment: You might want to explore setuptools. Create your setup.py and then you can generate wheel or tar.gz build dist from those.

Comment: Also you can push to pypi and pip install...